# How can I use rollmean() to add a rolling mean column to a dataframe?

Tags: r

I am looking to take a rolling mean measurement of one data column in a data frame and make it a new column pasted on the end of the dataframe. I have managed to get `rollmean()` to output the correct data, but cannot get it to become a new column. Here's the code I've tried:

```
aeris_data$RollMean <- rollmean(aeris_data$CH4, 29, na.pad = FALSE)
```

This returns the error:

> Error in $<-.data.frame`(`*tmp*`, RollMean, value =
> c(1.89297931034483, : replacement has 8611 rows, data has 8639

I don't have NAs at all, I looked through all 8500 lines to check, so what could explain this?

I will add: changing `na.pad = FALSE` to `na.pad = TRUE` binds the column, but all entries are NAs.

Comment: What package is this function from?

Comment: I think there's something to do with `rollmean()` not returning the same number of elements as it receives, even without `NA`. It is easy to see that with `rollmean(1:5,2)` having four numbers.

Comment: rollmean() is droping NA or NULL values. And as a result it has a different length then the number of rows in your data.frame. The documentation of rollmean() suggests that na.pad argument is depreciated, and you can avoid dropping NULL/NA by setting the 'fill' argument. All this advice may hinge of the version of zoo you are running.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error in the code shown in the question is due to that code specifying na.pad = FALSE.  In that case it will not pad the result and the result will have fewer values than rows resulting in an error.  Also na.pad=TRUE is deprecated and fill=NA is preferred.  With data.frames, unlike zoo objects, you can't append shorter columns.

**1)** Using the built-in 6 row BOD data frame and a width of 3 we can write this to take the mean of the 3 values up to and including the current value of demand, filling in components for which there are not 3 values available with NA.

```
library(zoo)

transform(BOD, mean_demand = rollmeanr(demand, 3, fill = NA))
```

giving:

```
  Time demand mean_demand
1    1    8.3          NA
2    2   10.3          NA
3    3   19.0    12.53333
4    4   16.0    15.10000
5    5   15.6    16.86667
6    7   19.8    17.13333
```

**2)** If you want the 3 values centered at the current value instead then remove the r at the end of rollmeanr.

**3)** If instead of NA's you want to fill in the first two values with the means of whatever values are available, even though there are less than 3, then use the following.

```
transform(BOD, mean_demand = rollapplyr(demand, 3, mean, partial = TRUE))
```

giving:

```
  Time demand mean_demand
1    1    8.3     8.30000
2    2   10.3     9.30000
3    3   19.0    12.53333
4    4   16.0    15.10000
5    5   15.6    16.86667
6    7   19.8    17.13333
```

**4)** Had BOD been a zoo object it would be OK to append a shorter column in this manner:

```
z <- read.zoo(BOD, drop = FALSE) # drop=FALSE to give 2d result
z$mean_demand <- rollmeanr(z$demand, 3)

z
```

giving:

```
  demand mean_demand
1    8.3          NA
2   10.3          NA
3   19.0    12.53333
4   16.0    15.10000
5   15.6    16.86667
7   19.8    17.13333
```